# Usage webpack with bower

Tags: npm, reactjs, bower, webpack

I have a basic ReactJS application. I use webpack and would like to use moduls from bower. I installed [bower-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-webpack-plugin) and add jquery library in bower.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var BowerWebpackPlugin = require("bower-webpack-plugin");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                //tell webpack to use jsx-loader for all *.jsx files
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BowerWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
        })
    ],
    externals: {
        //don't bundle the 'react' npm package with our bundle.js
        //but get it from a global 'React' variable
        'react': 'React'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            jquery: "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Now I am using [this webpack config](http://andrejgajdos.com/setting-up-webpack-for-es6-react-sass-and-bootstrap/) with bower dependencies and without *bower-webpack-plugin*

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "jquery",
  "version": "2.1.4",
  "main": "dist/jquery.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "build",
    "dist/cdn",
    "speed",
    "test",
    "*.md",
    "AUTHORS.txt",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "sizzle": "2.1.1-jquery.2.1.2",
    "requirejs": "2.1.10",
    "qunit": "1.14.0",
    "sinon": "1.8.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "jquery",
    "javascript",
    "library"
  ]
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic Property Grid</title>
    <!-- include react -->
    <script src="./node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- this is where the root react component will get rendered -->
    </div>
    <!-- include the webpack-dev-server script so our scripts get reloaded when we make a change -->
    <!-- we'll run the webpack dev server on port 8090, so make sure it is correct -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8090/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
    <!-- include the bundle that contains all our scripts, produced by webpack -->
    <!-- the bundle is served by the webpack-dev-server, so serve it also from localhost:8090 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8090/assets/bundle.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").append("This is Hello World by JQuery");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open main page, I get error message: "$ is not defined".

**project structure**

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/lpiepiora/bower-webpack-plugin/issues/14. The only workaround for the moment is to expose yourself `$`: window.$ = require('jquery');

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First**, maybe you just forgot, but to be sure, I want to point out that it seems you showed us the jquery `bower.json` file in your question. 
Your project doesn't actually seem to have a `bower.json` file at its root.

If you want to use Bower to manage dependencies, make sure you have a `bower.json` by running `bower init` at the root of your project and then run for instance `bower install --save jquery`.

See [the bower doc](http://bower.io/) for more info ;)

---

**Besides that**, the problem is that you're trying to use jQuery in `index.html`, so not in a webpack-managed module.
Webpack is not actually processing anything on your index.html.

What I mean is, put your jQuery code in `index.jsx`, instead of putting it in `index.html`:

```
// index.jsx
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").append("This is Hello World by JQuery");
});
```

**And it should work!**

You can also remove this code, since the `BowerWebpackPlugin` handles that for you:

```
alias: {
   jquery: "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
}
```

**How does it work?**

1. `index.jsx` is loaded through Webpack.
2. `$` is used as a free variable, but thanks to the `ProvidePlugin`, it will resolve to `require("jquery")`
3. `require("jquery")` resolves to import jQuery from the `bower components` folder
   thanks to the `BowerWepackPlugin`.

Without the `ProvidePlugin` and only the `BowerWebpackPlugin`, you would have had to write:

```
// index.jsx
var $ = require("jquery");

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").append("This is Hello World by JQuery");
});
```

Comment: First, sometimes you have to deal with legacy code and need to access to `$` in the view. Or you just need it to access it in your console, which is more convenient.
More, there is a real bug with the BowerWebpackPlugin, see: https://github.com/lpiepiora/bower-webpack-plugin/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

add a resolve field:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        jquery:"/your/path/to/jquery"
    }

}
```

and add this to your plugin:

```
 plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
        })
    ]
```

hope it helped

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. Please see my edited question.

Comment: My bad I forgot the alias field, I edited my answer let me know if it's good now

Comment: This is the direction to take you may have other issue idk but at some point you'll write this part :) . By the way I don't think you need to have index.jsx, index.html would be fine